# Python: sum column if matches

Tags: python, sum, multiple-columns

i have a huge file with thousand of lines that looks like this:

```
`C509.TCGA-78-7159-10A-01D-2036-08.1-C509.  1   0   0   1   0   0
 C509.TCGA-78-7159-10A-01D-2036-08.1-C509.  0   1   1   0   1   1`
```

If the first column of rows matches I want to sum second column of one row with second column of second row, third with third etc, **not using pandas**. And probably it would be better to use python, not awk because of the size.

The output should be:

> `C509.TCGA-78-7159-10A-01D-2036-08.1-C509. 1 1 1 1 1 1`

Thank you for help :)

Comment: How is this data stored? As a list of lists?

Comment: Can you give us your desired output please, in addition to the explanation with words.

Comment: @JahKnows data is stored in a file just like this, in columns.

Comment: @BcK  desired output would be  for example of this input: C509.TCGA-78-7159-10A-01D-2036-08.1-C509. 1  1  1  1  1  1

Comment: @Miss, what kind of file is it?

Comment: @Miss don't write me personally, edit your question to include that output.

Comment: @JahKnows it is the output file from another script (no extension) but it has to be in stored in this way. I will try to convert it to a list of lists to use your solution, thank you very much :)

Comment: @Miss you don't need to convert your input file, especially if it's very large as you mentioned in your Q. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something along these lines:

```
import re

res = dict()

with open("mydata.txt") as f:
  for line in f:
    id, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6 = re.split(r"\s+", line)
    res.setdefault(id, [0] * 6)
    res[id][0] += int(col1)
    res[id][1] += int(col2)
    res[id][2] += int(col3)
    # ... and so on for the rest of cols
```

output for your input is:

```
print(res)
{'C509.TCGA-78-7159-10A-01D-2036-08.1-C509.': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you load your data into Python as a list of lists you can do the following

```
from operator import add

data = [['C509.TCGA-78-7159-10A-01D-2036-08.1-C509.',  1,   0,   0,   1,   0,   0],
        ['C509.TCGA-78-7159-10A-01D-2036-08.1-C510.',  0,   1,   1,   0,   1,   1,],
        ['C509.TCGA-78-7159-10A-01D-2036-08.1-C509.',  1,   0,   0,   1,   1,   0],
        ['C509.TCGA-78-7159-10A-01D-2036-08.1-C509.',  1,   0,   0,   1,   0,   2],]

dic = {}
for i in data:
    if not i[0] in dic: dic.update({i[0]: i[1::]})
    else: dic[i[0]] = list(map(add, dic[i[0]], i[1::]))
```

This gives you a dictionary with each unique first value and the total sum of the other columns.

> {'C509.TCGA-78-7159-10A-01D-2036-08.1-C509.': [3, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2], 
>   'C509.TCGA-78-7159-10A-01D-2036-08.1-C510.': [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]}